# Tkinter ttk.PanedWindow sash position

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

Hi can anyone please tell me if there is a way to get the sash positon of a ttk PanedWindow. With tk.PanedWindow you can use sash_coord() but that doesn't seem to work for ttk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sashpos` method. It takes an index for the Nth sash. For example, if you just have a single sash separating two widgets, you would use the value 0 (zero):

```
pw = ttk.Panedwindow(...)
...
print(pw.sashpos(0))
```